# how to give subsubsection text same size as subsection?

Tags: sectioning, fontsize

how to make the text size of `\subsubsection` heading same as that of `\subsection`? I find `\subsubsection` text size too small and want the headings to be of the same size. Only `\section` heading can be bigger in size.

Answer (score 3):

it depends a bit how your current definitions are set up.

In `article` class the definitions are

```
\newcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
```

so if you added to the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

then subsubsection would be same as subsection, apart from the numbering.

Comment: currently i am using lncs format

Comment: @Alina well same applies just copy the lines from the class, although in the version of llncs.cls I found here http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mdr/movep/phd/llncs.cls subsection and subsubsection are already using the same size font

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Note the class sets both `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` to have normal size, so both should be changed:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatch{\subsection}{%
\normalsize}{%
\large}{}{}
\xpatch{\subsection}{%
\normalsize}{%
\large}{}{}
```

Comment: I want the subsubsection to look tike the subsection. just font and size while retaining the numbering.

Comment: Sorry I messed up with `\section`. It seems they already have the same size.

Comment: Ops, my bad. yes you are right. \section has the bigger size. other two have the same size. but xpatch didn't work for me .

Comment: Could you post a minimal (non-)working example?